# assessing accuracy within k-fold cross validation versus hold out data

Tags: python, machine-learning, cross-validation, k-fold

I have observed the mean accuracy after applying `Stratifiedkfold` is higher in comparison with the accuracy on the `holdout data`. I wonder if this can be a sign of over fitting in this case and if so, can someone explain.

Yhe accuracy on the `holdout` model is around 95.7% and on the Stratifiedkfold set is 96.3%.

Comment: rephrased the question

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your second paragraph, but yes. When the training accuracy is higher than the validation accuracy, it indicates overfitting. However, that is always the case (unless lucky). A small amount of overfitting is completely normal, like in your case.

BTW, this question is better suited for datascience.stackexchange or crossvalidated.stackexchange.